# one to many with mongoose

Tags: mongoose, one-to-many

I want to define a one-to-many relationship between my Student model and my Formation model: 1 student belongs to 1 formation and a formation can be composed of N students.

My needs are:

- be able to populate a Formation document with its students
- easily retrieve the Formation of a Student

So I wrote:

```
let student = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String
    },
    formation : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Formation'
    }
});

let formation = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    students: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }]
}
```

When I'm searching for documentation about the one-to-many relation with mongodb/mongoose, I'm surprised to see that when I want to create a Student document (and add it to a formation), I must not only set its "formation" field with the formation id and also push it to the formation document "students" field.
Does it imply that when I want to replace the formation of a student with another formation, I'll need to 1/ update its formation field 2/ remove myself the student id from the formation "students" field and re-add it to the students field of the new formation?
It seems a little redundant to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `students` on the Formation model is both bad practice and redundant. Potentially infinite arrays are a poor design as they can lead to hitting document size limits. In regards to being redundant, you only have two queries in this situation:

1) You have a `student` in memory, and you want to find their formation:

```
Formation.findOne({_id: student.formation},callback);
```

2) You have a `formation` in memory, and want to find all students in that formation:

```
Student.find({formation: formation._id}, callback);
```

Neither of which require having `students` on the Formation schema.

Comment: This works, but searching the student collection for each student with a given formation ID is much slower than searching for a given formation and returning the array of students, assuming there are more students than formations.

Comment: If the formation is indexed, you're really just getting into micro-optimization vs. proper design.

Comment: Its true that this is only relevant for a large database. Could you justify what you are calling "proper design"?

Comment: Due to the fact that operations on multiple documents are not atomic, updating information in two places has the potential to make your data inconsistent. So if you are storing the same information in two places and something breaks mid-update, your data doesn't match. You'll need to have tasks that run intermittently to make your data "eventually consistent".

Comment: Oh, I believe we had a misunderstanding. I meant for students as a property of formations, or vice versa. Obviously having both is bad practice.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. The reason then is specifically because of one-to-many. Having a student in an array on a formation doesn't restrict that student from being elsewhere. `formation.findOne({students: student._id})` can potentially find the wrong one if they ended up in two. It just grabs the first result in the sort order.

Comment: your discussion taught me more than 2 weeks of web browsing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact redundant because the way you have defined your schemas is redundant. The array of students should be a property of the formation, **but not the other way around**. Subdocuments can be searched like normal collections. If you change your schema to:

```
let student = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String
    }
});

let formation = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    students: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Student' }]
}
```

You should be able to accomplish your needs with fairly short commands. Assuming formations and students are your collection names:

1: Generating a student and saving both the formation and student documents.

```
var stud = new student({name: "Sally"}); //Assuming you modeled to student
stud.save(function (err, student) {
  formations.findOne({}, function (err, form) { //Dont know how you find formations, I assume you know
    form.students.push(stud._id);
    form.save(callback);
  }  
});
```

2. Retrieving the formation of a student with a given ID:

```
formations.findOne({"students" : { $elemMatch: {_id: id}}}, function (err, doc) {})
```

3. Even moving a student is relatively simple.

   `formNew.students.push (`

`formOld.students.pop(formOld.students.indexOf(formOld.students.findOne(
//elemMatch like above
)))`

Sorry about the weird formatting.