# Is there a difference between using a list of Embedded Documents or using a list of ObjectIds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/embedded-documents.html) I have come across this example:

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Comments]
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});
```

Is there a difference between doing that and this:

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});
```

where **comments** is an Array of ObjectIds?
I guess my question is really, will Mongoose create a collection for each of the Schemas or will it actually just embed Comments into BlogPost?

I'm asking because currently, in a project I'm doing, I have a Schema that has an Array of ObjectIds that represent Users. I'm wondering, instead of declaring an Array of ObjectIds, if I could declare an Array of Users.

Comment: I typically suggest [going the other way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33371750/3696076)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a big difference and your guess is correct.

**First version just embeds** the comments into BlogPost, there is only one collection `("BlogPosts")` in MongoDb. If you delete a BlogPost all its comments are deleted as well, because they only existed inside the BlogPost. One comment can only be inside one BlogPost. This is called "embedded subdocuments"

**Second version creates references**. So your BlogPost references the comments. Theoretically one and the same comment could be referenced by multiple blogposts. If you delete a BlogPost, the comments that were referenced by it will happily live on. This is called "Referenced documents": http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

For your last question: Embedding is probably not the right solution for users, because you might also need your users at other places and standalone. If you embed you often create redundant duplicates. Embedding is often a good solution for objects that really live within other objects and are not referenced/used from other places (e.g. a Comment of a BlogPost).