# One to many relationship mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
module.exports.addList = function(req, res){
    Category.find({_id: req.params.id, user_id: req.user.id}, function(err, category){
        category.lists.push(req.params.list_id);
        category.save(function(err, category){
            if(err){
                res.json({"Error": err.message})
                return console.log(err);
            }
            //find the list and then save the category id..?
            res.json({"Category": category})
        })
    })
}
```

So categories have many lists, this is a function to add a list.

This works fine, but then in the Lists schema I'm suppose to have a reference to the Category ID as well. Is the correct way to import the List schema and then query it with the id and then save it?

Comment: Maintaining an array of `list_id`s on the `Category` is redundant. You don't need the array at all if it's one to many. See this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33371750/3696076

Comment: I didn't design the schema I'm just doing the APIs